# How to print the items I bought without printing the items I did not bought?

Tags: java, arrays, swing

I have just finished ironing this program but I'm still having a problem. Whenever I'm finished buying, the program not only prints the items I bought but also the ones I did not. How can I do it? I just want to print the ones I bought.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class sto
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        char s;
        do
        {
            int pcod=0, qua=0;
            int[] cod={101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110};
            double[] pri={22.20,5.50,55,18.50,18.50,250,14.80,23,16.50,30};
            String[] pro={"Notebook","Ballpen","Ink","Eraser","Memo Pad","Staple","Pencil","Diskette","Ruler","Glue"};
            double[] sal=new double[10];
            int[] qu=new int[10];
            do
            {
                pcod=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter Product Code:"));
                if(pcod>0&&pcod<101||pcod>110)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"INVALID PRODUCT CODE"); 
                }
                else
                if(pcod>=101||pcod<=110)
                {
                    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
                    {
                        if(pcod==cod[i])
                        {
                            qua=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter quantity:"));
                            sal[i]=pri[i]*qua;
                            qu[i]=qua;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }while(pcod!=00);
            double tsal=0;
            for(int d=0;d<sal.length;d++)
            {
                tsal+=sal[d];
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Items Bought:");
            for(int i=0;i<sal.length;i++)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,pro[i]+" "+qu[i]+"x ................"+sal[i]);
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Total sales................"+tsal+" Pesos");
            s=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Thank You!!\n\nShop Again?(Y/N)").charAt(0);
        }
        while(s=='y');
    }
}
```

Comment: `if(pcod>=101||pcod<=110)` - This is always `true`. All numbers on earth are `>=101` or `<=110`.

Comment: @MarounMaroun All **real** numbers on earth...

Comment: @CPUTerminator Actually I wanted to mention this but I thought no one will point out to that ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sal.length is always 10. You could initialize all values in sal to 0.0 then only print if sal[i] != 0.0

Comment: I knew I had to use that, my problem was where to put it. But I figured it out.
Thanks mate!!